# I want to use instagram api for getting username from instagram for my android project

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagramapi-mgp25

After an update on 15 October 2019 Facebook updated their policy ,I don't know how to integrate with Instagram 
I tried out and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started with this like

but it gives me error like this :

> {“error_type”: “OAuthException”, “code”: 400, “error_message”:
>   “Invalid Client ID”}

I used Instagram App ID for client id, I don't know what I have to use ? App id or Instagram app id ?

Help me out on this.

Thanks.